# Trouble understanding re.findall pattern syntax

Tags: python-2.7, findall

Today I came across this line of code:

```
re.findall(r"#[^:]+:([^#]+)", str)
```

I am very confused about what pattern the `findall` function is looking for. Specifically what does `r"#[^:]+:([^#]+)"` mean?

I'm a high school student so if you could explain it in simple terms that would be awesome!

Comment: You should start reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and update your question.

Comment: In complement to reading the documentation, you can test your regex and get some explanation on how it works with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com).

Comment: How should I update it?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thanks for the website it helped a lot

Answer (score 3):

It is meaning this:

```
# => matches the character # literally (case sensitive)

[^:] => Match a single character that is not :

+ => Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) and is applied to the [^:]

: => matches the character : literally (case sensitive)

([^#]+) => Capturing Group

    [^#] => Match a single character not present in this list (match anything other than #)

    + => Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) and is applied to [^#]
```

And note that `r` literal means that the string which is quoted is a `raw` text, meaning that anything inside it does not have any special meaning to the compiler and you dont have to escape any character even double quotes!

Comment: This looks like a slight edit of [regex101's explanation](https://regex101.com) of this regex. It would be helpful to the OP to indicate this.

Comment: If `str = "# of k-points: 816 # of bands: 52 # of ions: 8"` What does the function return? Would it be `"# of k-points: 816"` or just `"816"`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes it is. I did understand the pattern and wanted to provide it myself, but the lack of time directed me to this helpful app to use that to make life easier for me.

Comment: @Joe Is this an regex?